# Abila MIP Fund Accounting default PDF export location

Tags: abila

I would like to set the default location for all my users in Abila MIP Fund Accounting. It looks like there is no place to change this in the UI and the Abila KB articles provide no insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Sysinternal's ProcMon while performing a PDF export job I was able to locate a read request for the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MIP\NT NonProfit Series\FundAccounting\System\ReportPDFFiles` which doesn't exist by default.

Creating a reg_sz with the value desired works as it should. This is unsupported by Abila support however.

Also note that this setting is machine wide. There is no HKCU equivalent request made.